# Open a word document and save it to another folder with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have working code that opens up a word document programmatically using vbscript, makes a change, then saves that same document and closes that same document.

Is it possible to do the same thing, but save the document to another folder and close out both instances of word?  I slightly modified my original code, but it only closed out the second instance of the word document that was saved.

Apparently, word thinks if I'm saving to another folder it needs 2 instances of the document.  This is some of my original code:

```
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFile.Path)
'modify the document.
etc...

objDoc.SaveAs objFSO.BuildPath(strDirectory, objFSO.GetFileName(objFile.Path))
objDoc.Close
```

this works fine for one document. Then all I changed was this, adding another directory to write to instead of the original:

```
objDoc.SaveAs objFSO.BuildPath(strDirectory & saveDir,  objFSO.GetFileName(objFile.Path))
```

and I ended up with two identical word documents opened and when I closed the one I was saving, the other stayed open.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to save the word document in the original folder and then write further code to move it into another location, perhaps using `FileSystemObject.MoveFile`. Don't rely on Word's "Save-as" functionality to do this - as you have observed you get a nasty side-effect.

Comment: Point well taken, that is what I needed. Thanks!